# How do I set a working directory for Java application?

Tags: java, filesystems

I've written a simple java app, say, with the following code:

```
String currentDir = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, currentDir); //This line shows a graphical dialog with the current dir
```

When I run it through the terminal, it gives me the directory where the jar-file is located. But when I run it using the GUI file manager (that is, right click on the jar-file -> Open With -> OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime) - the working directory is my user home directory (/home/angstrem). How can I set the working directory to be the one, in which the jar-file is situated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String jarPath = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

replacing `YourClass` with an actual class defined in your jar.

You can then make your file paths be relative to `jarPath`, and your program will work regardless of its working directory.

Comment: I can't actually understand, why does it work, but it does :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you shouldn't be able to. Consider multi-threading for example. You can only make your application current-path-insensitive.